# How to Prevent WinRar from deleting temporary files?

Tags: windows, compression, winrar, temporary-files

is there any way when I open a document in a compressed file by double clicking it using WinRar to prevent temporary files deletion after closing the WinRar instance?

I tried changing the extraction path to a folder in My Documents but it still deletes the file as soon as I close WinRar.

If anyone happens to know another software with such a feature please let me know.

Comment: it is called temporary with a reason. what do you want to achieve? if you need the file you should use file save as in app you opened the file directly from the winrar or extract the files to your My Documents (or wherever) and use them as files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option in the WinRAR settings and that's for a good reason: temporary files are meant to be temporary. If you want to extract the files, you use the Extract feature in WinRAR.

However, if you still want to keep all temporary files of WinRAR, you could set the "Folder for temporary files" (in Settings / Paths) to a folder where the users do not have the delete permission. To delete these files you will need to use an administrator account.

Comment: It's also possible to extract it to a RAMdisk using Imdisk or something similar, if you don't have disk space. Temp files can be extracted into RAM and left there until the computer reboots or shuts down. If WinRAR closes but the computer is still on, extracted files in RAMdisk stay there. Though its unlikely you have more RAM than you do free disk space; so it's best to extract it somewhere on disk instead

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible to keep temporary files of WinRAR for some time

Open WinRAR application then Click Options-Settings-Security-Select "**Wipe temporary files**" to **Never** and finally click on Ok

[image]

Comment: This setting does not prevent deletion of temporary files. Here is a quote from the WinRAR help:

Wipe temporary files/Never
If "Never" is selected, temporary files are removed using the standard system delete function and they can be recovered with special software sometimes. This is a fastest, but less secure way to deal with temporary files. 

Wipe temporary files/Always
In "Always" mode, before deleting temporary files are overwritten by zero bytes to prevent their recovery. This is a noticeably slower and more secure approach.